# Как вместо горизонт.разделительной серой линии (между медиафайлами в галереи) сделать горизонт.разделительную линию зеленого цвета?

Tags: wordpress

Как вместо горизонт.разделительной серой линии (для разграничения медиафайлов в галереи) сделать горизонт.разделительную линию зеленого цвета?

Этот вопрос является уточнением к предыдущему вопросу.

Answer (score 0):

Кодирование параметров горизонт.разделительной линии (для разграничения вертикальных медиафайлов в галереи) описывается в файле сброса стилей reset.css.
(Файл reset.css используется, чтобы установить значения свойств элементов в нужное состояние.) В самом Wordpress нету доступа к этому файлу сброса стилей reset.css. Для этого нужно зайти в папку на хостинге wp-content/themes/css/(может отличаться) и исправить код для HR с border-top: 3px solid #CCCCCC на border-top: 3px solid #00FF00.

Comment: Этот ответ проверен мною на практике.